# Cyclic dependencies in Nix/NixOS explained on a simple example

Tags: package-managers, nixos, nix

[Here](http://nixos.org/nix/manual/#ex-hello-composition) it is written in point 1:

> This file defines a set of attributes, all of which are concrete
>   derivations (i.e., not functions). In fact, we define a **mutually
>   recursive set of attributes.** That is, the attributes can refer to each
>   other. This is precisely what we want since we want to “plug” the
>   various packages into each other.

This seems a little bit difficult to understand.

For example if `derivation A` depends on `derivation B` and `derivation B` depends on `derivation A`, then how is such a mutually recursive pair of derivations built in Nix/NixOS ?

Could you please give a **simple example** how and why such mutually recursive derivations do not lead to problems ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If A depends on B and viceversa, it's a cyclic dependency and Nix cannot handle that.

But mutually recursive sets are a different thing. It just means A can depend on B of the same set:

```
rec {
  a = 1;
  b = 2;
  c = a+b;
}
```

As stated by jhegedus, it's equivalent to (because of laziness):

```
let s = with s; {
  a = 1;
  b = 2;
  c = a+b;
};
in s
```

But this is a cycle, and doesn't work:

```
rec {
  a = b;
  b = a;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll post this anyway because it is more than nothing and it might help someone:

Here in point 1: http://nixos.org/nix/manual/#ex-hello-composition, it is written : "we define a mutually recursive set of attributes", this is a little bit confusing. Does this not lead to chicken-egg problem ?

joco42_
Say, package 1 depends on package 2 but package 2 depends on package 1, isn't that a problem ?

joco42_
Can such cyclic dependencies really exist in nix ?

kmicu
No it’s not a proble

kmicu
m with Nix http://augustss.blogspot.hu/2011/05/more-points-for-lazy-evaluation-in.html

joco42_
kmicu: many thanks

kmicu
http://nixos.org/nix/manual/#sec-constructs

joco42_
kmicu: many thanks, I've just asked this on sof before i saw your comment [Cyclic dependencies in Nix/NixOS explained on a simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31368647/cyclic-dependencies-in-nix-nixos-explained-on-a-simple-example)

joco42_
kmicu: so basically nix expression are written  in a lazy language ?

kmicu
Yes, “The Nix expression language is a pure, lazy, functional language.”

(there is also an example at http://lethalman.blogspot.com/2014/11/nix-pill-17-nixpkgs-overriding-packages.html )

**Basically**, nix language can handle recursion because it is lazy:

```
nix-repl> fix=f : let r= f r ; in r

nix-repl> p= s: { a=3;b=4; c=s.a+s.b;}

nix-repl> fix p
{ a = 3; b = 4; c = 7; }
```